# Installing parallel Ubuntu alongside the productive system

Tags: encryption, luks

To make it short:

1. I am on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04, all apps are running (including special research software and all I need for my work)
2. I want to test the new Ubuntu (not Budgie, because Gnome got the horizontal workflow I use) 22.04 in parallel to the productive system
3. As I sometimes have sensitive data on my computer, the disk is encrypted (LUKS)
4. Ubuntu 22.04 installer only offers to erase everything, or custom installation, but there is no option to log into the encrypted system and create a new partition there

Actually, I would like to double boot, Ubuntu 20.04 Budgie, with Ubuntu 22.04 before 22.04 reaches at least the beta state and access my partitions from both systems. Before I started using encryption, i was no problem to shrink the original ubuntu partition and install the new system in parallel, to check if it is mature enough to be set up to my needs.

Is there a way to use two Ubuntu systems under one disk encryption?

Comment: Rather than overcomplicate partitions and whatnot, why not run the beta OS (or any other OS you want to test with) in a virtual machine? This will ensure your production system with all its settings and data remains isolated from whatever other system you’re testing 

Comment: That I already did. This phase of testing is over, I would like to move to the new system gradually, but if something does not work, move to the backup system. The thing is, someday I will only use the new system, this means I will set up my productive environment, which includes software for medical data visualisation, python, coding tools etc. It does not make sense to do all this work in a virtual machine. 
Before I used disk encryption, it was not a problem, now I need to know if there is a way to open the encrypted disk from the ubuntu installer and create a new partition there.